# How do I customize PostgreSQL configurations using helm chart?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy an application that uses PostgreSQL as a database to my minikube. I'm using helm as a package manager, and add have added PostgreSQL dependency to my requirements.yaml. Now the question is, how do I set postgres user, db and password for that deployment? Here's my `templates/applicaion.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: {{ template "sgm.fullname" . }}-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app: {{ template "sgm.fullname" . }}
  ports:
  - port: 80
    targetPort: 8080
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ template "sgm.fullname" . }}-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ template "sgm.fullname" . }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: {{ template "sgm.fullname" . }}
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: sgm
        image: mainserver/sgm
        env:
        - name: POSTGRES_HOST
          value: {{ template "postgres.fullname" . }}.default.svc.cluster.local
```

I've tried adding a configmap as it is stated in the postgres helm chart github Readme, but seems like I'm doing something wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is [lightly discussed in the Helm documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#scope-dependencies-and-values): your chart's `values.yaml` file contains configuration blocks for the charts it includes.  The GitHub page for the [Helm stable/postgresql chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/tree/master/stable/postgresql) lists out all of the options.

Either in your chart's `values.yaml` file, or in a separate YAML file you pass to the `helm install -f` option, you can set parameters like

```
postgresql:
  postgresqlDatabase: stackoverflow
  postgresqlPassword: enterImageDescriptionHere
```

Note that the chart doesn't create a non-admin user (unlike its sibling MySQL chart).  If you're okay with the "normal" database user having admin-level privileges (like creating and deleting databases) then you can set `postgresqlUser` here too.

In your own chart you can reference these values like any other

```
- name: PGUSER
  value: {{ .Values.postgresql.postgresqlUser }}
```

Comment: I was comparing your answer with the helm description, and I found out that those variables are referenced as `global.postgresql.*`. Is `global` some kind of a scope for values file? And if so, how do I refer to variables that don't belong to that scope? `replication.synchronousCommit` for instance

Comment: Yes, `global` has special status (see the first link in my answer): the PostgreSQL sub-chart sees only the content under `postgresql:`, plus `global:` merged in.  From your own chart you need to use `.Values.postgresql....` (or `.Values.global....`) as the last example shows.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that I need to define all the variables from the table under chart name tag, e.g. `postgresql`? 
So, `existingSecret` = `postgresql: existingSecret`?